# How do i reflect changes made by a function to a global variable in the main function?

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, python-multiprocessing

```
from num2words import num2words
import re
from googletrans import Translator
import time, os, glob
import concurrent.futures
start_time = time.time()
translator = Translator()
src_dir="/home/lol/patrika1"
dest_file="/home/lol/df.txt"
counter=1
def n2w(match):
    return translator.translate(num2words(int(match.group(1))),dest='hi').text
def clean_file(file_name):
    global counter
    fil = open(file_name,'r')
    lines = fil.read()
    fil.close()
    # more logic
    result=re.sub(r'[\n]+','\n',result2)
    counter+=1
    print(counter)
    print(file_name)
    cleaned.write(result)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global cleaned
    os.chdir(src_dir)
    file_list=glob.glob("*.txt")
    cleaned=open(dest_file,'a')
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(clean_file,file_list[:10])
    print("finish "+ str(counter))
    cleaned.close()
```

Counter has a value 1 in the main function when i print.
How do i maintain a count of how many files have been processed by the function?

Answer (score 0):

As usually global variable use is not advised ( what does it count ? who modifies it ? and the case where 2 scripts to merge use the same "counter" for 2 different things ), you could use that type of construct :

```
class FileCleaner:
    Counter = 0

    @classmethod
    def clean(cls, file_name):
        ...
        cls.Counter +=1
        ...
```

and then access FileCleaner.Counter from anywhere and call function with FileCleaner.clean( ... )

maybe try cleaner code before using ProcessPoolExecutor model, as it does not give easy to read code ( hopefully will be helped soon by subinterpreters) you would need to split the list of files, call executor in try/except , add +1 to the class counter on success all that from a file cleaning pool class. not from main.

```
import concurrent.futures
import threading
import math

PRIMES = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293,
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419]


class PrimePoolTester:

    Counter = 0


    @classmethod
    def is_prime(cls,n):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return False

        sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
        for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True

    @classmethod
    def execute(cls,primes):
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            for number, prime in zip(primes, executor.map(cls.is_prime, primes)):
                cls.Counter += 1
                print('(%s)-%d : %d is prime: %s' % (threading.current_thread().name, cls.Counter, number, prime))



class Runner_interpreter:
    def __init__(self, thread_count, worker):
        self.thr = []
        for _ in range(thread_count):
            t = threading.Thread(target = worker)
            t.daemon  = True
            t.start()
            self.thr.append( t )

    def join(self):
        for th in self.thr:
            th.join()




if __name__ == '__main__':

    def job():
        global worklist
        PrimePoolTester.execute( worklist.pop(0) )


    worklist = [ PRIMES  ] * 4

    #use 4 "core"
    Runner_interpreter(4,job).join()
```